# Why do some submits replace the whole view and some not when using Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using Ajax.BeginForm on an MVC4 Razor page, and we're having problems doing a normal submit. If we post using `<input id="Reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />`, the entire page will be replaced with the partial view we're returning, but if we add an onchange event to a checkbutton (`@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyValue, new { onchange = "$(this).closest('form').submit();" })`) it works and the partial view gets replaced as it should. How come one type of submit works and not the other?

**Update:** It works on the first submit, but not the second.

We've tried adding an onclick event with the same call as the onchange event has, but same thing happens. `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is referenced. There is a 404 on the network tab for `jquery-1.10.0.min.map` which is referred to in a comment on `jquery-1.10.0.min.js`, but we've tried removing it and still getting the same result. `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is set to true in the web.config. The div that we want to replace is located within the form and we have set `UpdateTargetId` to its id when specifying the AjaxOptions.

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "Post", 
            UpdateTargetId = "FilteredList", 
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        }))
{
    // google map javascript etc removed for brevity

    <div id="FilteredList">

        // html code removed for brevity

        // this works
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyValue, new { onchange = "$(this).closest('form').submit();" })

        // this doesn't work
        <input id="Reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />

    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{   // logic to get the model
    return PartialView("FilteredList", model);
}
```

Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-easing-1.3.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-cycle-3.0.2.all.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/libs/bootstrap.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
onchange = "$(this).closest('form')[0].submit();"
```

Notice the `[0]`. In this case I am invoking the `.submit` method on the raw DOM element and not on the element returned by the jQuery selector. So basically I am calling the native `submit` event and not jQuery's.

No need to explain the difference between the 2, you've already experienced it :-)

Comment: It's the other way round that I need though - if I use this for the checkboxes onchange event then they won't work either. At least it's consistent, but I'd prefer the opposite consistency. :)

Comment: But +1 for explaining the difference between calling the native submit and JQuery's.

Comment: If you have properly included jquery and after it jquery.unobtrusive-ajax the Ajax.BeginForm will work as expected. There seems to be some script that is doing something strange. Try disabling every scripts you might have except jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.

Comment: I've tried disabling all scripts but no luck. Will keep trying, just thought I'd mention I noticed that it only fails on the second submit. If I hit the button first it works fine, but if I hit the checkbox first or the button for a second time it fails.

Comment: Does the partial view you are injecting contains some scripts? Also are you replacing this form in the AJAX call?

Comment: Yep, it's got the google maps scripts plus a couple of other things (it still failed when we commented out all of them though).

Comment: Which version of the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script are you using? Is there a line like this in it: `$(document).on("submit", "form[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) { ...`

Comment: Not sure which version, I'll check, but yes, that line is in there.

Comment: Can you send me a narrowed down version of the Visual Studio project exhibiting the problem? I cannot see anything wrong from the provided description and this scenario should work.

Comment: We moved the Ajax.BeginForm within the div it's replacing, and now it works. I thought it was meant to be outside? I'll still try to create a narrowed down version as I'm curious how it works.